# Getting 404 NOT_FOUND with python bottle webtest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, bottle, webtest

I'm trying to use [WebTest](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/) (version 2.0.20) to test a simple health-check endpoint in a python bottle application, but I'm getting AppError 404 response all the time. Am I missing something?

in my server file:

```
from bottle import Bottle

application = Bottle()

@application.route("/check")
def check():
    return "Up and running!"
```

in my test file:

```
import httplib
import unittest

import webtest
from should_dsl import should
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

from myservice.server import application


@attr("component_test")
class ServerComponentTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_health_check_should_return_OK(self):
        """ test health check endpoint should return OK"""
        app = webtest.TestApp(application)
        app.get(url="/health")
        response.status | should | equal_to(httplib.OK)
```

running `nosetests` yields the following:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test health check endpoint should return OK
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../myservice_env/myservice/test/__init__.py", line 41, in test_health_check_should_return_OK
    app.get(url="/health")
  File "..../myservice_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/app.py", line 323, in get
    expect_errors=expect_errors)
  File "..../myservice_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/app.py", line 632, in do_request
    self._check_status(status, res)
  File "..../myservice_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webtest/app.py", line 664, in _check_status
    res)
AppError: Bad response: 404 Not Found (not 200 OK or 3xx redirect for http://localhost/health)

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: 404 Not Found</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans;}
              body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
              pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: 404 Not Found</h1>
            <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://localhost:80/health&#039;</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>Not found: &#039;/health&#039;</pre>
        </body>
    </html>


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.010s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: alright it was a blind mistake (facepalm), i used /health endpoint instead of /check

Comment: Answer your question and mark it as resolve.